# Google maps preload closer zoom / Zoom fast

Tags: performance, maps, zooming, preload

I use google maps with some markers. A click on a marker zooms to it. But I looks very shitty because google maps first zooms in and loads the closer map after.
It would be so awesome if there is a way to make it look like google maps on my iPhone!

(I hope u get the problem, if not, just ask)

So my question: 
Is there any way/hack to preload the closer map?